# Optimizing sed command or create new one

Tags: sed

I'm trying to filter a really big log file and wondering if there are any alternatives for my commands? or some optimizing?
here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
nice -20 sed '/./{H;$!d;};x;/37455299339/!d' 1.txt > /tmp/new.txt
nice -20 sed -n '/Acct-Status-Type/,/NAS-Identifier/p' /tmp/new.txt > /tmp/new_1.txt
rm /tmp/new.txt
nice -20 sed '/Acct-Status-Type/{x;p;x;}' /tmp/new_1.txt > /tmp/new_2.txt
rm /tmp/new_1.txt
nice -20 less /tmp/new_2.txt | grep -A1 -B1 37455299339 | grep -A1 -B1 User-Name > new_3.txt
```

Comment: You can try `sed -i`

Comment: sed -i for which command? for all?

Comment: Yep, it updates the files in place, so you can get rid of the `>` and `rm` parts.

Comment: Tried, did not helped. Actually I have the problem with RAM. It is 1GB. I need to optimize somehow this script to have ability to run with 1GB RAM. Now there is an error message that "sed: couldn't re-allocate memory"...
P.S. log file is very big, ~9GB.

Comment: Rather than providing the sed commands, you should explain the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: I have explained as you see... So, if you cannot help me, please don't teach.

Comment: @user37033 Whith `{H;$!d;}`, you're storing whole input file in ram. In actual *state of knowledge*, we could'not help you. Give us some lines of input as sample and explain what's your goal.

Answer (score 2):

As first step, I would remove all temporary files and use pipe instead: from first `sed` you may pipe stdout to second one and then to third one. Then, your `less` command is useless: just pipe again from the third `sed` to `grep`.

Using pipe you will have many benefits: first you will not waste your disk space, second, you will not wait for all these disk I/O.

For better finding a solution, you should tell us what is currently blocking you: is it one of the `sed` commands? Which one?